# Ubuntu Advantage: Difference between xenial-infra-security and xenial-infra-updates

Tags: ubuntu, security

1. Question:

When you install Ubuntu Advantage (package `ubuntu-advantage-tools`) on Xenial, and enable only `esm-infra` service, it installs the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list` with the two following lines:

```
deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-security main
deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-updates main
```

`xenial-infra-security` ok, I want to have that.
But what is the purpose of `xenial-infra-updates` ?

Is it the same style like having xenial-security and xenial-updates in /etc/apt/sources.list ?

I only have the following in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb         http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/        xenial                  main restricted universe multiverse
deb         http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu           xenial-security         main restricted universe multiverse
```

so *no* xenial-updates since we only wanted to have pure security updates and no more (e.g. bugfix) updates (to keep the change minimal), should/could one then delete the entry `xenial-infra-updates`? Did not find any documentation about that.

2. Question:

Having an Ubuntu Xenial Host with the following `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb         http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/        xenial                  main restricted universe multiverse
deb         http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu           xenial-security         main restricted universe multiverse
deb         http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu           xenial-updates          main restricted universe multiverse
```

so *with* `xenial-updates`, would it be ok to have only the following `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list`

```
deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-security main
```

so *no* `xenial-infra-updates`, to keep the ESM-Updates minimal security-only? (background: we learned that once you enabled `xenial-updates` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` you cannot remove it anymore, because afterwards you cannot install new packages that depend on other packages that had been updated through `xenial-updates`, so the version of the depended package is newer than the to-be-installed package expects, so you have broken dependencies)

It would be nice if both questions could be answered with either yes or no, and if second question can be answered with yes, I would appreciate an explanation why exactly that would be.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Security Team at Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ)

**-updates**:

> includes things that have gone through the StableReleaseUpdates process, and contain various important bug fixes.
> Anything built for "-updates" is built on top of which ever version of
> a package is newest between "-updates" and "-security", so that
> nothing in "-updates" will introduce security regressions.

While **-security**:

> includes only updated packages that contain security-related fixes, and are built to not require anything from "-updates". Anything
> built for "-security" is built on top of which ever version of a
> package is newest between "-updates" and "-security", so that nothing
> in "-security" will introduce bug regressions.

Thus, if you are ok with having the system without bug fixes and enhancements, you can simply comment out the update line, in your case:

```
deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-updates main
```

Comment: Edit: I expanded to a second question.